# Insert a number into a string with regex and reuse the old values

Tags: regex, insert

I want to change the date 31.12.16 to 31.12.2016

My code until now:

```
import re
mystring = "31.12.16"
mystring = re.sub(r'(\d\d.\d\d.)(\d\d)', r'\120\2', mystring)
```

But how to insert the number 20 in the end of this code line?

```
print(mystring) # gives me 'P16'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
import re 
mystring = "31.12.16"
mystring = re.sub(r'(\d\d\.\d\d\.)(\d\d)', r'\g<1>20\2', mystring)
```

The literal dots must be escaped and `\g<1>` is an unambiguous backreference to Group 1.

Comment: Note that you get `P` because `\120` is parsed as an octal value that is equal to decimal 80, that is `P` in the ASCII table.